# socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable with google app engine

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, google-app-engine, proxy

I am making a sudoku app for google app engine in python(2.7.6) with the webapp2 framework. I was able to deploy this app from my local dev environment up till 2 days ago. Today, when I tried to deploy it again, it gave the error

```
2015-08-15 04:48:32,851 ERROR appcfg.py:2438 An error occurred processing file '': [Errno 101] Network is unreachable. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
run_file(__file__, globals())
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5445, in <module>
main(sys.argv)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5436, in main
result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2997, in Run
self.action(self)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5092, in __call__
return method()
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3815, in Update
self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3868, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3753, in UpdateVersion
return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2428, in DoUpload
self.error_fh)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 482, in GetResourceLimits
resource_limits.update(_GetRemoteResourceLimits(logging_context))
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 452, in _GetRemoteResourceLimits
yaml_data = logging_context.Send('/api/appversion/getresourcelimits')
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1738, in Send
result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 245, in Send
url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1584, in request
(response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1332, in _request
(response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1306, in _conn_request
conn.connect()
File "/home/quantumcoder/Documents/program-files/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1053, in connect
raise socket.error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

I have not kept a record of the various configuration files I had changed in the last 2 days.( I am using ubuntu GNOME on a dell laptop). 
I tried solutions suggested in other similar questions, like changing ipv6 settings, and checking connection through urllib2, but they did not work.
(I can connect via urllib2)
My app directory sudoku-aniket contains

```
app.yaml          easypuz3.txt    easysoln2.txt~       page.html
app.yaml~         easypuz3.txt~   easysoln3.txt        stylesheets
bootstrap.min.js  easypuz4.txt~   easysoln3.txt~       sudoku       (copy).py
easypuz1.txt      easypuz5.txt~   images               sudoku.py
easypuz1.txt~     easysoln1.txt   jquery-2.1.4.min.js  sudoku.pyc
easypuz2.txt      easysoln1.txt~  output.txt           sudokusolver.py
easypuz2.txt~     easysoln2.txt   output.txt~          test.py
```

my network proxy settings are http://proxy22.iiyd.ernet.in:3128

my app.yaml file is

```
application: sudoku-aniket
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
module: default

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: numpy
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: sudoku.app
```

What can be the error here?

Comment: *proxy settings sre http://proxy22.iitd.ernet.in:3128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the command tries to access https://accounts.google.com, change your https proxy settings accordingly.
 This worked well for me.
For example, int this case, execute

```
    export https_proxy="https://proxy22.iitd.ernet.in:3128"
```

in terminal .